pod error. conflicting versions library SSZipArchive react-native-code-push with react-native-zip-archive
when running pod install, i have 2 conflicting libraries,
react-native-code-push and react-native-zip-archive that depend on different versions of SSZipArchive.
how do i solve this?
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SSZipArchive":
  In Podfile:
    CodePush (from `../node_modules/react-native-code-push`) was resolved to 8.3.1, which depends on
      SSZipArchive (~> 2.2.2)

    RNZipArchive (from `../node_modules/react-native-zip-archive`) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
      SSZipArchive (~> 2.5.5)

Specs satisfying the `SSZipArchive (~> 2.5.5), SSZipArchive (~> 2.2.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

links i tried

https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive/issues/151
https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive/issues/72


You need to upgrade your platform version to 15.5
platform :ios, '15.5'

This worked for me. :)
